# Show percentage in Qt Pie Charts?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts

How to show percentage in [Qt Pie charts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-piechart-example.html) on chart like this? [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: @AustinD, only getting percentage from QPiSlice and adding value of it to label!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this task you have to enable to make the labels visible and place the position as LabelInsideHorizontal, in the following code the solution is shown.

```
series->setLabelsVisible();
series->setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice::LabelInsideHorizontal);

for(auto slice : series->slices())
    slice->setLabel(QString("%1%").arg(100*slice->percentage(), 0, 'f', 1));
```

[image]

PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
    series.append("Jane", 1)
    series.append("Joe", 2)
    series.append("Andy", 3)
    series.append("Barbara", 4)
    series.append("Axel", 5)

    chart = QtChart.QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.setTitle("Simple piechart example")
    chart.legend().hide()

    series.setLabelsVisible()
    series.setLabelsPosition(QtChart.QPieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal)

    for slice in series.slices():
        slice.setLabel("{:.1f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))

    chartView = QtChart.QChartView(chart)
    chartView.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView)
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: thanks, how can I change color of label text? using pieSlice->setPen does not change pen color.

Comment: You must use `setLabelBrush`, ie: `slice->setLabelBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));`

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the color of the lable text inside the slices?